# Modify function's code in wrapper function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Is it possible to replace the actual code of a function by the function that wraps it? Here I'm trying to replace `print` statements with `log` statements:

```
import logging
import re

def print_to_log(func):
    def wrapper_print_to_log(*args, **kwargs):
        # how to do something like this?
        re.sub(r'print\s*\(',  'logging.info(', **function_code**)
        return func(*args, **wargs)
    return wrapper_print_to_log


@print_to_log
def greet(name='bob'):
    print ("Hello, %s" % name)
    print ("How are you sir?")
```

Is it possible to replace the code or do something similar to the above?

Comment: Is your goal here to have flexibility in logging, or are you really interested in dynamically rewriting code, and the code here is just an example?

Comment: @bjudson actually to rewrite the code -- logging is just an example.

Comment: have you explored monkey patching (eg the `unittest.mock` module)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can temporarily replace sys.stdout?

```
import logging
import re
import sys
import io

def print_to_log(func):
    def wrapper_print_to_log(*args, **kwargs):
        stdout = sys.stdout
        b = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = b
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.stdout = stdout
            print(b.getvalue().upper())

    return wrapper_print_to_log

@print_to_log
def greet(name='bob'):
    print("Hello, %s" % name)
    print("How are you sir?")

greet('justin')
```

Comment: Apparently, on python 3, you can also replace the built-in `print` function with any other function: `print = logging.info`. Just use the finally block to restore the `print` back to the built-in function afterwards.

Comment: Odd... replacing print seems to only work from the interactive prompt.

Comment: Ahh... but one can assign to `builtins.print` after `import builtins`. But now I am curious as to whether what the OP wants is actually possible.